# Chart JS dataset disabled by default

Tags: chart.js

When you click on the legend of a chart you can disable the display of that dataset. Is there a way of starting the chart display with a dataset turned off?
This is version 2 + of chart.js

Answer (score 5):

Found buried in the commit logs that you can add hidden:true, to a data set to disable it by default.